# Can Emacs enriched-text be displayed by other applications, browsers?

Tags: text-properties, rendering, enriched-mode

Emacs enriched-text stores test properties like font and colours that can be quite useful (colours in build logs, RTF-like documents, etc...)

Is there any other applications capable of rendering Emacs enriched-text files.  For instance is it possible to get Firefox display them?

Answer (score 4):

The `etc/enriched.txt` file points out that the basic file format is the `text/enriched` MIME format described by RFC1896:

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1896.txt

> Enriched-mode documents are saved in an extended version of a
> format called text/enriched, which is defined as part of the MIME
> standard.  This means that your documents are transportable (even
> through email) to many other systems.  In the future other file
> formats may be supported as well.

However:

> Since Emacs adds some non-standard features to the format (colors
> and read-only regions), not all systems will be able to recreate
> all of the features of your document, but they will get as close
> as possible.

So if other things support text/enriched generally, I would make that the focus of your searches.  I don't know whether anything does, but as a standard and SGML-like MIME format with a simple conversion to SGML/HTML, I'd rather expect that things would do so.

The two appendices are noteworthy in that regard:

- Appendix A -- A Simple enriched-to-plain Translator in C

> One of the major goals in the design of the text/enriched subtype of
> the text Content-Type is to make formatted text so simple that even
> text-only mailers will implement enriched-to-plain-text translators,
> thus increasing the likelihood that multifont text will become "safe"
> to use very widely. To demonstrate this simplicity, what follows is a
> simple C program that converts text/enriched input into plain text
> output. Note that the local newline convention (the single character
> represented by "\n") is assumed by this program, but that special
> CRLF handling might be necessary on some systems.

- Appendix B -- A Simple enriched-to-HTML Translator in C

> It is fully expected that other text formatting standards like HTML
> and SGML will supplant text/enriched in Internet mail. It is also
> likely that as this happens, recipients of text/enriched mail will
> wish to view such mail with an HTML viewer. To this end, the
> following is a simple example of a C program to convert text/enriched
> to HTML. Since the current version of HTML at the time of this
> document's publication is HTML 2.0 defined in [RFC-1866], this
> program converts to that standard.  There are several text/enriched
> commands that have no HTML 2.0 equivalent. In those cases, this
> program simply puts those commands into processing instructions; that
> is, surrounded by "<?" and ">". As in Appendix A, the local newline
> convention (the single character represented by "\n") is assumed by
> this program, but special CRLF handling might be necessary on some
> systems.

Comment: Good answer. Thx.